# AWS SQL Server RDS (unable to get local issuer certificate)

Tags: sql-server, amazon-web-services, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

> SQLSTATE[08001]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server]SSL Provider: [error:1416F086:SSL routines:tls_process_server_certificate:certificate verify failed:unable to get local issuer certificate]

I'm using AWS RDS, and I've already installed all the requirements for the sqlsrv driver. However, when I try to connect from my UBUNTU SERVER, this is what I encounter on sqlcmd. Is there another way to configure this in UBUNTU SERVER settings?

Comment: If you're using a modern version of `sqlcmd` then the `sqlcmd -?` help reveals the `-C Trust Server Certificate` option. Have you tried that?

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue.

After having had trouble trying to get the CA pem (downloaded from AWS's servers) trusted in Linux using certificate commands, I was able to fix it this way without having to disable certificate verification:

```bash
certFilename=/usr/local/share/ca-certificates/global-bundle.crt
sudo wget https://truststore.pki.rds.amazonaws.com/global/global-bundle.pem -O $certFilename
sudo ln -snf $certFilename /etc/ssl/certs/df65e9bd.0
```

No restarting of any services needed.

Here's the GitHub comment where I first wrote this: https://github.com/microsoft/msphpsql/issues/1417#issuecomment-1465160379